# How to find out the solid color used for the Windows Wallpaper?

Tags: windows, registry, wallpaper

I know how to retrieve the wallpaper from the registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\Wallpaper
```

But what if the user chooses to use a solid color as a wallpaper, how do I retrieve that specific color?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve it from

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Colors\Background
```

It is a string containing a space-seperated tuple "R G B", e.g. "255 0 0" for red,  "255 102 0" for orange.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx) for information on acquiring the registry value using C#, C++, F#, and VB.NET.

And the example below for Powershell

```
# PowerShell Registry Key example
$Registry_Key = "HCU:\Control Panel\Colors\"
Get-ItemProperty -path $Registry_Key -name Background
```

Comment: I did it and the value is changing in the registry but the color of the background doesn't, if i tried from the control panel, it will work, any suggestions?