# Changing the solid desktop background color in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, background-color

I'm trying to change the solid desktop background color, and i'm using a `RegistryKey` to do that like so :

```
Dim CD As New ColorDialog
If CD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim RK As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Control Panel\Colors", True)
    RK.SetValue("Background", CD.Color.R & " " & CD.Color.G & " " & CD.Color.B)
End If
```

I'v seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608017/how-to-find-out-the-solid-color-used-for-the-windows-wallpaper), but it didn't help in my case.

The code above is working because the value in the registry editor is changing, but the background color is not, if i edited the color from the control panel, it will change the same value in the registry editor and the background color will change, anyone have explaining for that, or is there any other way to do it?

Comment: That question talks about READING the background color, changing it is a more bit complex: [Set Desktop Wallpaper to a Solid Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7309943/c-set-desktop-wallpaper-to-a-solid-color)

Comment: @Steve , Thanks to you, i'v got it, and i made an answer about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it to work, it can't be done by only editing the registry key, in fact you need to use the `user32.dll` API to do so, and you can use the registry key to get the value of the color only, but not to set it, thanks to [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve) **(↑)**.

Here is what worked for me :

**First >** Declare this function to use the API :

```
 Private Declare Function SetSysColors Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal one As Integer, ByRef element As Integer, ByRef color As Integer) As Boolean
```

**Second >** Use this to call the function and change the color :

```
Dim CD As New ColorDialog
If CD.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim BackgroundColor As Integer = ColorTranslator.ToWin32(CD.Color)
    SetSysColors(1, 1, BackgroundColor)
End If
```

**Hope that was useful to someone :)**